# Javascript generic search of array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to come up with a function that allows for a deep generic search of an array of objects, even nested object data like this:

```js
let orders = [
{
  id: 7,
  order_number: 1234
  address: {
    last_name: "Anderson",
    first_name: "John"
  }
},
{
  id: 8,
  order_number: 4321,
  address: {
    last_name: "Franko",
    first_name: "Billy",
  }
}
]
```

The function needs to be flexible enough to handle any String or Numeric data and search the entire array of objects **without needed to know which fields to search for, should search the entire objects fields**

So for example something like this would work:

```js
let searchedData = searchData(orders, 'john')
```

Would return:

```
[
{
  id: 7,
  order_number: 1234
  address: {
    last_name: "Anderson",
    first_name: "John"
  }
}
]
```

And

```
let searchedData = searchData(orders, '4321')
```

Would return:

```
[
{
  id: 8,
  order_number: 4321,
  address: {
    last_name: "Franko",
    first_name: "Billy",
  }
}
]
```

This would need to be able to work to unlimited levels deep, the depth of the objects will not be known.

It also needs to be case insensitive.

I did the following function:

```js
searchData(arr, query) {
  let data = [];

  for(let item of arr) {
    if(item.order_number.includes(query) || item.address.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(query) ||   item.address.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(query)) {
      data.push(item);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is this function isn't abstract enough to work with any array of objects.

Comment: What about partial matches like `searchData(orders, 'Fran')` should that return the object whose name is `Franko`? If so, what should the behavior be for numbers?

Comment: Partial martches should add the object for both strings and numbers

Comment: You mean that `searchData(orders, '12')` should also return the object whose `order_number` is 1234?

Comment: Yes exactly that's correct

Comment: So the `query` parameter is always a string, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple recursive inner function. You may need to modify the matching condition to suit your needs.

```js
let orders = [ { id: 7, order_number: 1234, address: { last_name: "Anderson", first_name: "John" } }, { id: 8, order_number: 4321, address: { last_name: "Franko", first_name: "Billy", } } ];
function searchData(data, val){
  function find(data){
    if(data===val||data.toString && val.toString && data.toString().toLowerCase().includes(val.toString().toLowerCase()))return true;//you can modify the matching condition
    return data===Object(data) && Object.values(data).some(find);
  }
  return (Array.isArray(data)?data:Object.values(data)).filter(find);
}
console.log(searchData(orders, 'John'));
console.log(searchData(orders, '4321'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this part `return orders.filter(o=>find(o, val));` be `return data.filter(o=>find(o, val));` ?

Comment: @Jordash Good catch.

Comment: This is a good solution, I'm trying to figure out if there's anyway for it to also work on an object of objects / arrays in addition to an array of objects? To make it more flexible.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, it needs to work for partial matches as well and be case-insensitive, this solution doesn't handle those cases

Comment: @Jordash You can just modify the matching condition for those cases, i.e. change `if(data===val)` to your own condition.

Comment: @Jordash I have modified the function to work for objects too.

Comment: @Jordash I've modified it to allow partial string matches.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify it a bit:

```js
searchData(arr, query) {
  let data = [];
  let re = new RegExp(query, 'i');

  for (let item of arr) {
    for (let p in item) {
      if (re.test(item[p]))
        data.push(item[p]);
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

I use regex so that it's case-insensitive, and return the "data" var at the end (which is important).
This isn't recursive, so it won't handle your nested objects, but you can add that in pretty easily but just testing the type of item[p], running the function and merging what's returned.
However, you won't get the property of what's being searched, and that may be what you're after. For that, you would need to push a new object instead of just the value.
But hopefully this helps some.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach by looking to objects and find in the values.

```js
const
    searchData = (data, val) => {
        const
            isObject = o => o && typeof o === 'object',
            find = o => o === val
                || o.toString() === val.toString()
                || isObject(o) && Object.values(o).some(find);

        return data.filter(find);
    };

let orders = [ { id: 7, order_number: 1234, address: { last_name: "Anderson", first_name: "John" } }, { id: 8, order_number: 4321, address: { last_name: "Franko", first_name: "Billy", } } ];

console.log(searchData(orders, 'John'));
console.log(searchData(orders, '4321'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```